# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual::getUsedProducts()

Tags: magento2.4.3

I am trying to fix this bug:

It looks like there is/are a deleted product(s):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual::getUsedProducts() in
> .../app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_subchild/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml:335
> Stack trace: #0
> .../vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):
> include() #1
> .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct),
> '/home/ecommerc/...', Array) #2
> .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/ecommerc/...')
> #3 .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() #4
> .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1103):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{
> in
> .../app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_subchild/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
> on line 335

Comment: Please add fragment of code near line 335 (before and after) in `app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_subchild/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`. This will help to answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Check your app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_subchild/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 335, try to comment it, then save.
Then remove pub/static/frontend folder and run setup:static-content:deploy -f command. then check again.

Now if it works, then good, otherwise try to check the code in list.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of my products is Virtual Product. I change the weight dropdown from "item has no weight" to "item has weight" and put something on the lbs textbox. The solution is to convert Virtual Product to Simple Product.

And the page displayed smoothly with that error.